# Spark rdd cached but not reused

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and runs multiple iterations with that dataframe.

```
val raw = getDataframe() // <-- the is Stage 3 operation.

val df = raw.repartition(2000, col("id")) // <-- start stage 4
            .dropDuplicates(Seq("id"))
            .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)

// do iterative jobs..
// job2
// job3
// job4
// ...
```

## Job 2

- There is a cached point at stage 4 (mapPartitionsInternal)
- because of this is the first iteration, all stages and operations need to be operated.
  [image]

## Job 3

- Stage 3 has skipped
- But, First 5 blue boxes at the Stage 4 is not skipped even those are cached from the **Job2**
  [image]

## Questions

- Spark only skips by stage level? but not for task of operation level?
- SortAggregates at the stage 4 may be a `dropDuplicate` operation. How can I dropDuplicates just once?
- Will `raw.count()` after `dropDuplicate()` divid a stage into two and `dropDuplicate` will skipped from the second iteration?

## Update 1

I added count() after persist.

```
val df = raw.repartition(2000, col("id")) // <-- start stage 4
            .dropDuplicates(Seq("id"))
            .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)

df.count()
df.explain(true) <-- plan A

// do iterative jobs..
// job2
// iterativejob.explain(true) <-- plan B
```

#### Iterative job sample

Iterative jobs are cubing sql. something like.

```
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("tb")

    dataframes = dataframes :+ sqlContext.sql(
      s"""
         | SELECT
         |   d_scene_id, d_action_id, d_classifier,
         |   count(*) m_event,
         |   approx_count_distinct(user_key, ${rsd}) m_user,
         |   approx_count_distinct(device_id, ${rsd}) m_device,
         |   3 dimension_count
         | FROM tb
         | GROUP BY d_scene_id, d_action_id, d_classifier
         |""".stripMargin)
```

#### compare plans again

Then compared two physical plans here.
https://github.com/jeesim2/test/pull/1/files?diff=split&w=1

Left one is the plan of A, right one is the plan of B.

As you can see trees before and including `InMemoryRelation(cache)` are exactly same at both side.

```
+- InMemoryRelation [event_time#13, scene_id#14, action_id#15, classifier#16, event_hash#0, user_key#3, device_id#11, product#4, country#77, os_name#157, app_ver#117, p0name#197, p0value#597, p1name#237, p1value#637, p2name#277, p2value#677, p3name#317, p3value#717, p4name#357, p4value#757, p5name#397, p5value#797, p6name#437, ... 7 more fields], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, 1 replicas)
```

Then, Why `SortAggregate(key=[event_hash#0])`(dropDuplicates('event_hash')) recalculated every iteration?

Comment: Have you tried running only df.count and without iterative jobs? That way you can compare which parts of the logical plan happen after the persist operation. Persist/cache will materialise df up to the point where you call the persisting action and truncate the locigal plan, this will limit the scope of catalyst optimisation. Could you also share some code of your iterative jobs to be able to better reason about the diagrams?

Comment: @milos I have updated some. Could you please take a look once again?

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like everything is working correctly.
Two sortAgregates stages are in the schedule due to approx_count_distinct over a different column.

Your cache happens after a WholeStageCodegen that corresponds to repartition on a column and drop duplicates on the same column. Exchange corresponds to exchanging these partitions to corresponding executors.

At this point those new partitions are cached at executors and when iterative job 2 is triggered these stages are skipped.

So to answer on the circled stages and "is this recomputed" the answer is yes, but based on provided information that is supposed to happen.